# is it possible to submit html form -Data with image resized at client side before submitting the form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Suppose i have the following form

```
<form name="my-form" method="post" action="handler.php">
<p>
<input type="text" name="cname" placeholder="Enter your name here" id="cname"/>
</p>
</p>
<input type="file" id="imageid" name="imageid"/>
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</p>

</form>
```

Now i want to resize the image before submitting the form. i have to following javascript code to handle the submit event

```
function processForm(e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
//what to do here?

    return false;
}

var form = document.getElementById('my-form');
if (form.attachEvent) {
    form.attachEvent("submit", processForm);
} else {
    form.addEventListener("submit", processForm);
}
```

before that i used to resize the image at server side using php. But i want to do this process at client side.. but i don't know how to accomplish this.

Comment: You should keep on doing it on the serverside

Comment: Serverside is the best option for sure. Can't think of a good reason to do this client side..

Comment: @adeneo if i do this at client side then it will help in making this process much faster as image data will be lesser than the original size thus will help in saving bandwidth.

Comment: Whatever floats your goat ...

Answer (score 1):

In HTML 5 you can resize images client-side using the canvas element. You can also take the new data and send it to a server. See this tutorial:

http://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/01/how-to-develop-a-html5-image-uploader/